# How do I make a discord.py bot that logs events?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For example, if I were to log an event, I’d say >log and then the bot would DM me asking questions, first off “What’s your username?” “Did you have a Co-Host? Put N/A if none” “How many attendees? (#)” “Usernames of who passed?” “# of who failed?” “Image?” then it would make a log in a channel saying:
Host: (username)
Co-Host: (username or N/A)
Attendees: #
Passed: (usernames)
Failed: (usernames)
Proof: (image)

so anyways, how do I make this? Can someone send it? (I use @bot.command() form)

I didn’t try anything yet, I don’t know how to start

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can implement this using the discord.py library in Python:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def log(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send("What's your username?")
    username = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    username = username.content

    await ctx.send("Did you have a Co-Host? Put N/A if none")
    co_host = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    co_host = co_host.content

    await ctx.send("How many attendees? (#)")
    attendees = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    attendees = attendees.content

    await ctx.send("Usernames of who passed? (Separate with spaces)")
    passed = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    passed = passed.content.split()

    await ctx.send("# of who failed?")
    failed_count = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    failed_count = failed_count.content

    failed = []
    for i in range(int(failed_count)):
        await ctx.send(f"Username of failed attendee {i+1}?")
        failed_user = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        failed.append(failed_user.content)

    await ctx.send("Please provide an image (attachment) as proof.")
    image = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    proof = image.attachments[0].url

    log_message = f"Host: {username}\nCo-Host: {co_host}\nAttendees: {attendees}\nPassed: {', '.join(passed)}\nFailed: {', '.join(failed)}\nProof: {proof}"

    # You can change the channel ID to the desired channel where you want the log to be posted
    log_channel = bot.get_channel(123456789)  
    await log_channel.send(log_message)

    await ctx.send("Log created successfully!")

bot.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE')
```

Note: You'll need to replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE' with your actual bot token, and also update the log_channel variable to the appropriate channel ID where you want the log to be posted. Additionally, you may need to install the discord.py library if you haven't already done so, using pip install discord.py.

Answer (score 0):

The following code could be used as a starting point. For some context, I'm building a discord.py bot from scratch using slash commands and the documentation.

```py
@bot.command()
async def log(ctx):
    author = ctx.author
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
    
    await author.send("What's your username?")
    response = await bot.waitfor('message', check=check)
    username = response.content
```